# How we can use Simple Injector Bootstrapper in .NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

How we can use Simple Injector Bootstrapper in .NET Core Web Api project? Actually we trying to use external library for simple injector here is the code:

```
public static class IdentityServerBootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container, IEnumerable<Assembly> assemblies = null, bool verifyContainer = true)
    {
        container.Register<ISUPCoreApiClient>(() => new SUPCoreApiClient("https://localhost:44329/"));

        if (verifyContainer)
        {
            container.Verify();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the bootstrapper class in web api project

```
 public class WebApiBootstrapper
{
    public static void Bootstrap(Container container)
    {

        IdentityServerBootstrapper.Bootstrap(container, null, false);

        container.Verify();
    }
}
```

Here is the startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();



        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

        WebApiBootstrapper.Bootstrap(container);
    }
```

But its not working..

Comment: Check this out http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html

Comment: actually i m looking for define simple injector in external library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original solution of how to set this up is found [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html)

I implemented it with some extensions instead which IMO is a more nice approach.

Extensions

```
public static class ConfigureContainerExtensions
{
    public static void Bootstrap(this IServiceCollection services, Container container)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
            new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));

        services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
    }

    public static void InitializeContainer(this IApplicationBuilder app, 
        Container container, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
        WebApiBootstrapper.Bootstrap(container);
    }
}
```

And use them in startup class:

```
private Container _container;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Bootstrap(_container);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.InitializeContainer(_container, Configuration);
}
```